# How can the Custom Paths for Xcode be set from the command-line?

Tags: xcode

In Xcode the Preferences under Locations allow for manually setting Custom Paths. I'd like to read and write these values from the command-line. I do not see options in `xcodebuild` for doing this.

How can it be done?

[image: Custom Paths]

By having Custom Paths set I can then use them for relative paths which is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by using the `defaults` command to update the `NSUserDefaults` of Xcode.

https://gist.github.com/brennanMKE/7d9f190859a0f15fdc32c0811bf24386

```
# Note: Xcode shows these values in Settings -> Locations -> Custom Paths
# Xcode does not hot reload these values so you must restart Xcode to get the changes.

# Define a dictionary entry for LUMBERJACK_DIR with a display name
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEApplicationwideBuildSettings -dict-add LUMBERJACK_DIR "\$LUMBERJACK_DIR"
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDESourceTreeDisplayNames -dict-add LUMBERJACK_DIR "Lumberjack 1.0"

# Change the display name
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDESourceTreeDisplayNames -dict-add LUMBERJACK_DIR "Lumberjack 2.0"

# View the values which match this key
defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEApplicationwideBuildSettings | grep LUMBERJACK_DIR
defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode IDESourceTreeDisplayNames | grep LUMBERJACK_DIR

# Your Xcode project can define the $LUMBERJACK_DIR value in an .xcconfig variable.
# Be sure to add your .xcconfig to your project configuration for your current build configuration.
```